# When using .htaccess redirect, how do I test what the REQUEST_URI is?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do something really simple here but it's kicking my butt haha. I have my website, and I got a SSL certificate for it this morning. I want my users to be redirected to the secure site, but I only need the certificate for a certain portion of my website so I don't want to worry about everywhere else. The certificate is made to `domain.com` not `www.domain.com`. The part of my website where I need the certificate, all of the pages are in the `apps` directory. For example `domain.com/apps/login.php`. Here is what I have been putting in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/apps/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Now I will explain what I think this should be doing and I would like to be told where I'm wrong haha.

- `RewriteEngin On` - Allows redirects
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/apps/.*$` - Checks if user is in the apps directory
- `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` - Checks if user is already using https://
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` - Redirect

This partially works. When I type in `www.domain.com/apps/login.php` it redirects to `https://domain.com/apps/login.php`. Perfect. But if I just type in `www.domain.com` it redirects to `https://domain.com`. So it seems that my line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/apps/.*$` is broken. What do I need to put there to make it so that it only redirects to the secure site when they are in the `apps` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule looks to me like it should work, but in any case you don't need the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` test.  Just include `^apps` in the `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^apps/(.*)$ https://domain.com/apps/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: One question. How do I make the test case-insensitive?

Comment: @Aust use `[R=301,L,NC]`.  `NC` means "no case".

Comment: I didn't realize I could put that flag in the `RewriteRule` as well as the `RewriteCond` thanks. :)